# How to extract last values in regex in a string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I want to extract the last value from this string
JJ 11 J 1111 ABCD EFGH­ HIJK.S LMNOPQR 1234 55555 STUV ABCD EFGH 6789 1011. I tried (\d{4}) and (?<=\s.*\s.*\s.*\s.*\s.*\s.*\s.*\s.*\s.*\s.*\s.*\s.*\s.*\s.*\s.*).* but if the middle value some how changes this does not work.

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? As you're labelling with `javascript` you could as well use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring#using_substring_with_length_property

Answer (score 1):

```
.{4}$
```

That matches the last 4 characters of any string.

[image: proof]

**EDIT 1:**
This one matches the last word in a string

```
([\S]+)$
```

Comment: Actually the values are dynamic so either they are 4 digits or in this form  BB1BB1B00111111 so I want to extract only the last values

Comment: What are the last values for that string then? BB1BB1B00111111

Comment: This one BB1BB1B00111111. Either this will be the last value or four digits.

Comment: Try with this one: ([\S]+)$

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
"JJ 11 J 1111 ABCD EFGH­ HIJK.S LMNOPQR 1234 55555 STUV ABCD EFGH 6789 1011".match(/([\S]+)$/g)
```